# Gitlab not deleting backups

Tags: git, gitlab, backup, gitlab-omnibus

We are using a AWS ec2-instance for gitlab with omnibus installation, Recently gitlab has not been deleting the backup files and disk is filling up. I am not sure which log i should be seeing for this issue.

When i do `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create --trace`
so there is no error message, what could be the reason for not deleting the old backups? Please point me in the right direction.

```
Deleting old backups ... done. (0 removed)
```

my backup configuration:

```
### Backup Settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/backups.html

 gitlab_rails['manage_backup_path'] = true
 gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/backups"

###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#backup-archive-permissions
 gitlab_rails['backup_archive_permissions'] = 0644

# gitlab_rails['backup_pg_schema'] = 'public'

###! The duration in seconds to keep backups before they are allowed to be deleted
 gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800
```

**Gitlab -version**

```
gitlab-ce 10.2.2
```

Answer (score 4):

i could not find why its happening but to solve it, i have created another cron job to delete the backups that deletes if its past 2 days.

> 0 8 * * tue,thu,sat find /var/opt/gitlab/backups/15* -mtime +1 -type f
>   -delete

Comment: Thanks! this helped a lot!. I have to use -name in order to the correct permissions to do wild cards. Also, 15* no longer works since we are up to epoc 16* now. (this below deletes any tar older than 120 days)
`0 18 * * 5 find /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ -mtime +120 -type f -name "*gitlab_backup.tar" -delete`

Comment: ....This answer helped me find the directory of Gitlab's backups. Appreciate it!